# Cannot apply an external plugin in a gradle init script (github project included)

Tags: gradle

First off, I created a project to illustrate the issue I'm having:

`GitHub project removed, see edit for effective file contents. If you want the sample project PM me`

Try to run the project with the following command:

```
$./gradlew -I deploy.gradle tasks
```

I get an error like so:

```
Failed to notify action.
> Plugin with id 'artifactory' not found.
```

But when I include the contents of `deploy.gradle` in `build.gradle` it builds just fine. For the record it's the `artifactory` plugin, and it appears to only be in the jfrog repository. I'm sure I must be missing how to specify the classpath in the init script.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I was able to get it to work thanks to @erdi's answer. Here are the effective contents of the two files:

*deploy.gradle*

```
initscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/gradle-plugins' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:2.0.16'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPlugin
}

// vim:ft=groovy:tw=0
```

*build.gradle*

```
println 'Hello, world!'
// wrapper task omitted
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_i_include_buildscript_block_from_external_gradle_script) you cannot use plugin IDs in plugins scripts. Instead, the fully qualified class name has to be used.

Comment: Brilliant! That fixed the issue. I'll update the question when I get the chance to reflect the changes in code I had to make.