# Apply a gradle plugin with a common configuration to all projects

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

I have a workspace with multiple unrelated gradle projects. I'm looking for a way to apply the artifactory plugin to all of them with a common configuration.

So far, I tried creating this common gradle file, and applying it to each  project (top level, not module) using `apply from`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
            url 'http://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/plugins-release'    
        } 
    }

    dependencies {
     classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.1.1"
  }

}


if (!project.plugins.findPlugin("com.jfrog.artifactory"))
  project.apply(plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory")

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            maven = true
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release'
            maven = true
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error when building:

```
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.jfrog.artifactory']
   > Plugin with id 'com.jfrog.artifactory' not found.
```

How can I get this scheme to work?

Comment: The buildscript has to be defined at the root build.gradle file in a multi-module project. The buildscript blocks in subprojects are ignored. That might be what's causing the plugin to not be found.

Comment: @BenManes Gretty's (tomcat/jetty plugin for gradle) seems to do it successfully, however it doesn't work in my case. Here's they're "getting started" guide: https://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Getting-started.html 
They suggest adding "apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/akhikhl/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'" to build.gradle to get the plugin

Comment: Yes, but that has to be applied on the root project and not subproject. I'm not sure if that is your issue, but it sounds similar to mistakes users have reported when setting up my plugins.

Comment: In particular this reminds me of this [issue](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin/issues/47)

Comment: @BenManes yeah, that does look similar, however the project I'm trying to apply it to is a completely standalone java project that might as well be a gradle "HelloWorld". It's not a a module of a multi-project build.

Comment: odd... I'd just go step by step then. First do it normally, and try to gradually extract parts into a common script. Hopefully then you'll where it fails and the subtle mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it to work.

The "right" way of doing this is probably, as [JBaruch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) mentioned, using an init script. The problem is that Gradle (version 2.6 in my case) can't add a plugin by its id in an init script. It's a bug known (at least) from June 2012 (see [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-include-buildscript-block-from-external-gradle-script/7016)). I found it thanks to [this SO answer from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14600210/3199595).

Having said that, OP's solution from 2013 (posted in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14595606/3199595) itself) doesn't work anymore due to changes in the artifactory plugin itself. Specifically, the plugin's fully qualified name is no longer `org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPlugin`. There are now (Version 3.1.1) two plugins for gradle 2:

`org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPublicationsGradle2Plugin`
and 
`org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryConfigurationsGradle2Plugin`

So here's a working init script:

```groovy
initscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryConfigurationsGradle2Plugin //Note the lack of quotation marks
    apply plugin: org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPublicationsGradle2Plugin //Note the lack of quotation marks

    artifactory {
        contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
        publish {
            repository {
                repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
                maven = true
            }
        }
        resolve {
            repository {
                repoKey = 'libs-release'
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
                maven = true
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

**Edit:**

Another, simpler, solution is just to remove the artifactory plugin entirely, and replace it with `maven-publish`. Like so:

```groovy
allprojects {

    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    publishing {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url  "${artifactory_contextUrl}/"+ (version.contains('SNAPSHOT') ? 'libs-snapshot-local' : 'libs-release-local')
                credentials {
                    username "${artifactory_user}"
                    password "${artifactory_password}"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()

        maven {
            url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/libs-release"
            credentials {
                username "${artifactory_user}"
                password "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }

        maven {
            url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/libs-snapshot"
            credentials {
                username "${artifactory_user}"
                password "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JBaruch Init scripts are only part of the solution since it's tricky to load external plugins in the init script, and things might break if the plugin's class name(s) change in future versions. I'm still waiting to see if someone can come up with a cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, the best way to inject common configuration for unrelated projects is by using [an init script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html). In it you can configure the common behavior, including applying the Artifactory plugin.

Comment: That sounds right, but I still can't get it to work. I defined the jcenter repository and the org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle classpath in the initscript, but I get a "Plugin with id 'com.jfrog.artifactory' not found." when I try to apply the plugin. Can you maybe point me to a working example?

Comment: Ok, so i turns out that the problem is that you can't add a plugin by its id in an init script (see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14600210/3199595).