# How can I apply the Gradle Versions Plugin from an initscript?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to set things up so that I can use the [Gradle Versions Plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin) without having to add it to all of my `build.gradle` files.

Based on [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32332914/90848), I tried creating a file `~/.gradle/init.d/50-ben-manes-versions.gradle`:

```
initscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.17.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: com.github.ben-manes.versions
}
```

If I then try to invoke `./gradlew dependencyUpdates` in my repo, I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script '~/.gradle/init.d/50-ben-manes-versions.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
Could not get unknown property 'com' for root project 'project-name' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

That answer said to not use quotes around the plugin name, but since that didn't work I tried adding quotes (ie: `apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'`). With that I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script '~/.gradle/init.d/50-ben-manes-versions.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
Plugin with id 'com.github.ben-manes.versions' not found.
```

Is there any way to apply the Gradle Versions Plugin from an initscript?

I am using Gradle 4.3.1, by the way.

Comment: First thing is `com.github.ben-manes.versions` is not surrounded by quotes. When you apply a plugin like that, you are applying it by the id.

Comment: @mkobit As mentioned in the question, I tried both with and without quotes.

Comment: Sorry, totally my fault, I'm laying in bed and missed that. I'll take a look at this tomorrow.

Comment: @mkobit no problem! I thought the no-quotes version looked word too, but that other answer seemed to imply that the lack of quotes was important. Anyway, if you're able to take another look tomorrow I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plugins can be applied in a few different ways. In the referenced answer from the question, they are being [applied by type](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginManager.html#apply-java.lang.Class-). You can also [apply by plugin Id, which is a `String`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginManager.html#apply-java.lang.String-).

In your second attempt when you are applying by Id you are doing the right thing, but the build errors out with:

> Plugin with id 'com.github.ben-manes.versions' not found.

The issue here is that you [currently cannot apply plugins by Id from init scripts (#gradle/1322)](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1322).

The solution is to instead, apply the plugin by type.

Luckily, the plugin is open source so it relatively simple to discover the type of the plugin. The plugin Id is `com.github.ben-manes.versions`, which leads us to the [`META-INF/gradle-plugins/com.github.ben-manes.versions.properties` file](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin/blob/e39a84307cea47892149f576461c80fdb3b95d2f/src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/com.github.ben-manes.versions.properties). This file contains the line `implementation-class=com.github.benmanes.gradle.versions.VersionsPlugin`, which tells us that the type of the plugin is
 [`com.github.benmanes.gradle.versions.VersionsPlugin`](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin/blob/e39a84307cea47892149f576461c80fdb3b95d2f/src/main/groovy/com/github/benmanes/gradle/versions/VersionsPlugin.groovy#L10). This could have also be determined by applying the plugin to the build (instead of through an init script) and inspecting the `plugins` or `pluginManager` from the project to list out the plugin types.

To make the fix change this line:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'
```

to:

```groovy
apply plugin: com.github.benmanes.gradle.versions.VersionsPlugin
```

So the full, working initscript is:

```groovy
initscript {                                                                    
    repositories {                                                              
       jcenter()                                                                
    }                                                                           

    dependencies {                                                              
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.17.0'          
    }                                                                           
}                                                                               


allprojects {                                                                   
    apply plugin: com.github.benmanes.gradle.versions.VersionsPlugin            
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer that actually explains what's going on here!

Comment: Doing so results in `Could not get unknown property 'com' for root project 'edited' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: @Brice is that from an init script? Might be easier with a new question and full example.

Comment: @mkobit I don't reqally understand what was wrong. However my project sricpt is apply external script that have other buildscript seciton. So moving the `apply plugin` elsewhere in those scripts worked.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the solution from @mkobit for a while now. It works great, however it does not support the case when the project you are working on already has the versions plugin applied.

I am using a slightly modified version of the script now that does not apply the plugin if it already exists (in Groovy DSL):

```
initscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.42.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.parent == null) {
            def hasPlugin = project.plugins.any {
                it.class.name == "com.github.benmanes.gradle.versions.VersionsPlugin"
            }

            if (!hasPlugin) {
                project.apply plugin: com.github.benmanes.gradle.versions.VersionsPlugin
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: There is now an API to ask if a plugin has been applied. Example in Kotlin DSL

```kotlin
initscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.42.0")
    }
}
// don't use rootProject as it may not be ready
allprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        if (parent == null) {
            if (!plugins.hasPlugin("com.github.ben-manes.versions")) {
                apply<com.github.benmanes.gradle.versions.VersionsPlugin>()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with Gradle 7.4